# Import error:No module named _gdal

Tags: gdal, error, import, fwtools, python-2

I have installed python 2.5.1 and FWTools2.4.7 in my laptop(Windows 7)
when i run my pythonscript in FWTools i get following error
Import error:No module named _gdal
can any one suggest how to solve this problem?

Comment: gdal is a separate module from fwtools and python. your script must try to use it. you can build your own or use the osgeo4w. you don't state what your os is.

Comment: Dear BradMy os is windows 7 professional,service pack 1,x86-based pc.How to use osgeo4w

Comment: Please add requested info to edited question. Osge4w is complete installation of open gis tools with all dependencies. Otherwise you should become proficient in all dependencies.

Comment: I cant solve my problem yet. Python version in FWTools is 2.3.4 but my installed python is 2.5.1 . May be due to this I am getting this problem. It would be better if somebody provides me step by step procedure because I am very new to this

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of sending a comment as an answer.

Comment: If you follow the steps from user30184, the script will rum with python 2.3.4. This is shipped with the FWtools, and gets activated with setfw.bat. You have to open a DOS shell and do everything inside it. If it does not help, rename the Python 2.5 folder until you are finished with FWtools. And don't forget the `python` before the script name.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I'm running Polygonize from Qgis.
I'm using QGIS 2.6.1. version and the plug-in gdal is present. Where should be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking FWTools is pretty old and it should be used with care. However, FWTools is very easy to install and therefore I keep FWTools 2.0.6 and a few more versions always with me on USB stick.

FWTools includes its own python and at least those python scripts which are included in the \bin directory of FWTools should work without troubles.

- Open the Windows command window
- Set environment by running `setfw.bat`
- Test if python is found and which version it is with `python -V`. FWTools 2.0.6 has python v. 2.3.4.
- Test with some of the included scripts, for example

> `python bin\gdal2tiles.py`

You should see some messages from the script.

For some reason you must launch the script as `python script.py` or otherwise I get exactly the same error than you:

```
C:\FWTools2.0.6>gdal2tiles.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\FWTOOL~1.6\bin\gdal2tiles.py", line 38, in <module>
    import gdal
  File "c:\FWTOOL~1.6\pymod\gdal.py", line 191, in <module>
    import _gdal
ImportError: No module named _gdal
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use FWTools anymore. It is outdated.

Current GDAL for Windows with python support is available via OSGEO4W (which works with Python 2.7), or from [this link](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php)

Comment: FWTools is old but it works still as it worked when it was young. It contains bugs which have been found and corrected later and new GDAL is for sure better. However, if used with care FWTools can still be a good set of tools with no trouble with installation.